# HTML layout centered

Tags: css, layout, html

I am trying to create a HTML layout and I have created a number of  elements and given them a border etc in my CSS. I am trying to have the main  'Wrapper' centered so everything that goes inside this element are also centered.

I have tried everything, margin, align, absolute etc and nothing is working. My  stays situated in the top left corner of my page.

This is my index page where the  elements are:

```
<!--#include file ="inc.heads.asp"-->

<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
 <div id ="divWrapper">
  <div id ="divHeader">
   <img src="Images/title.png">
   <br>
   <div id ="divNavBar">
    <br>
     <div id ="divContent">
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

and this is my CSS:

```
body {
 background-color: #300;
}

#divWrapper {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 800px;
}

#divHeader {
 width: 500px;
 border-style: inset;
 border-color: #COCOCO;
 background-color: #707070;
 padding: 5px;
}

#divNavBar {
width: 500px;
border-style: inset;
border-color: #COCOCO;
background-color: #707070;
padding: 5px;
}

#divContent {
 float: left;
 width: 500px;
 border-style: inset;
 border-color: #COCOCO;
 background-color: #707070;
 padding: 5px;
}
```

If someone could possibly shed some light on why none of the things I have tried work and what a possible solution could be.

Thanks!

Comment: I have some unrelated learning points for you: 1. Why are you putting `<br>` after all those elements when they are already block level by default anyway?  If you need spacing, use CSS, not random line breaks; 2. `divHeader` is not a good `id`.  `Header` would be a better one, don't assume that just because the `id` is tied to a `div` now it will remain so as your page/site is developed.

Comment: As far as your actual question is concerned: what is in inc.heads.asp?  Does it include a `<DOCTYPE html>` to trigger standards mode in the browser?

Comment: @robertc - I have given each <div> a border and when I viewed it in IE they were all bunched together, so I just added a line break in to split them up and have a bit of space between them. as for the inc.heads.asp, it holds the code for my CSS.

Comment: Use `margin` to split things up and have a bit of space between them.  If all inc.heads.asp contains is CSS then what you have there is an invalid HTML document, it's not surprising it doesn't work.  CSS, if it's in the page, should go inside the `<head>`.

Comment: It seems to do [exactly what it's supposed to do](http://fiddle.jshell.net/adAXp/1/show/) if you put the markup and CSS in a valid document (I took the `<br>`s out).

Comment: I learnt to use another file such as the head file to keep links in for files such as CSS and JavaScript files. If it's wrong I can get rid. So I need to take all the CSS from my style.css and put it in the <head> of my index page?

Answer (score 0):

```
#divWrapper{
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
}
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: The problem isn't with centering `#divWrapper`- he already has this declaration (albeit in the combined form: `margin: 0 auto`). It's a problem centering the **content**!

Comment: margin: 0 auto; will do the same, so no valid answer

Comment: Well yes margin: 0 auto should do it but unfortunately it won't work at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `margin: 0 auto` to the contents of `#divWrapper`:

For example, add to your CSS:

```
#divWrapper * {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

If you only want the `div` elements to be centered, use:

```
#divWrapper div {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

You can see a working demo here > http://jsfiddle.net/gu7Sr/

Also, as a side note, try to avoid using `<br />` for creating your layout. It won't scale well and you'll have a tough time redesigning in the future!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want. **Link** : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ihzxp

```
<body>
 <div id="divWrapper">
  <div id="divHeader">
   <img src="http://blog.codepen.io/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Button-Fill-Black-Small.png">
   <div id="divNavBar">
     <div id="divContent">
       Stuff
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

and

```
body {
 background-color: #300;
}

#divWrapper {
 width: 100%;
}

#divHeader {
 width: 600px;
 border-style: inset;
 border-color: #COCOCO;
 background-color: #707070;
 padding: 5px;
margin: 5px auto;
 text-align:center;
}

#divNavBar {
width: 550px;
border-style: inset;
border-color: #COCOCO;
background-color: #707070;
padding: 15px;
margin: 5px auto;
}

#divContent {
 width: 500px;
 border-style: inset;
 border-color: #COCOCO;
 background-color: #707070;
 padding: 5px;
 margin: 5px auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

More just a comment to BenM's answer, but I don't have the reputation to comment yet.
Pretty sure just:

```
margin:auto;
```

will do the trick by itself.

Comment: It will, unless he needs to control the top and bottom margins independently of the centering.

Answer (score 0):

Seriously what is the point of all those wrappers? Just do this:

```
body {width: 800px; margin: 0 auto; }
```